# imdb get only movie summary java (xml)

Tags: java, xml, imdb

Is there some easy way to get the summary of an imdb movie as a String value in a Java-programm. I have a program that contains imdb-id's and I want the storyline of that movie to be shown in my application.

I don't know if imdb has some kind of easy way to do this. Because I have some troubles with using xml.

http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2820852&plot=full&r=xml

Comment: Do you have parsing problems with xml, or is it an understanding problem?

Comment: understanding problem, do I have to create a new class or something?

Comment: Do you have an xml file for a movie? Or you want to find a way to obtain one

Comment: Try to use SAX Parser http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Comment: I added a link to the webpage wich could be an example xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer JAXB and this is how you do it with JAXB:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("imdb.xml"); // use your stream source
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<Root> imdb = um.unmarshal(new StreamSource(stream), Root.class);
    System.out.println(imdb.getValue().movie.plot);
}

public class Root {
    @XmlElement(name="movie")
    public Movie movie;    
}

public class Movie {
    @XmlAttribute(name="plot")
    public String plot;
    // Add fields for other attributes you want to read
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer a DOM parser when I have small xml files.

This is one way of doing what you want. I printed the values but you can store them in strings or whatever suits your needs.

```
try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("your_xml_here.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("movie");

        /*
         * This for is if you have more than one movie in an xml. If not you
         * could just do the Node nNode = nList.item(0)
         */
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Title : " + eElement.getAttribute("title"));
                System.out.println("Year: " + eElement.getAttribute("year"));
                // here is your plot
                System.out.println("Plot: " + eElement.getAttribute("plot")); 
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

> Title : Furious 7
>   Year : 2015
>   Plot : Dominic Torretto and his crew thought...